# Restart service after suspend after a certain amount of time

Tags: systemd, services, suspend

I am running a service called "thinkfan" for controlling the fan speed of my thinkpad laptop. The service reads the data temperature from a temporary file in a folder. This file is created every now and then, but if thinkfan happens to be started before the file is created it will crash. To prevent this on boot, I added the line

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 20
```

to the systemd file

```
[Unit]
Description=simple and lightweight fan control program
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/thinkfan
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 20
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/thinkfan $DAEMON_ARGS
PIDFile=/var/run/thinkfan.pid
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is that the same occurs on wake up from standby, so I am looking for a way to restart the service after a few seconds every time my laptop wakes up after resuming.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it: just change the systemd file to

```
[Unit]
Description=simple and lightweight fan control program
After=syslog.target
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/thinkfan
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 20
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/thinkfan $DAEMON_ARGS
PIDFile=/var/run/thinkfan.pid
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

where I simply added `After=suspend.target` and `Restart=always`.